# I have searched for information trying to speed up my MySQL query and found a lot of info that just confused me. None seemed to address my issue

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two tables named Header and Detail. Both tables have an InvoiceNumber (double) column and a YearMonthCode (char4) column.

In the header table there is a column LastChangedDate (char(10) and in the detail table there is a column ItemNumber (varchar(16)) and OrderedQty (integer)

Before I go further let me say that I did not design these tables and cannot change them other than to add or remove indexes or stored procedures. I would not have stored dates as strings but I have to deal with it in the following form (mm-dd-yyyy)

The header table has about 900,000 records and the detail table as about 2,500,000 records
The yearmonthcode column goes from 1301 (January 2013) to 1312 (December 2013)

The objective of my query is to return the sum(OrderedQty) for a specific item over a set lastdatechage range.

Here is the query that I came up with and it does return the information that I need BUT it takes about 30 seconds to 45 seconds per item and the overall project reports on 600 to 100 items.....

I have this as a stored Procedure
GetItemTotal(in itm varchar(16), in ymcode (char(4), in SDate Date, in EDate Date, out total int)

```
Select sum(D.OrderedQty) into total 
FROM Header H use index (index_YMC) 
Inner Join Detail D use index (index_YMC) 
on H.invoicenumber = D.InvoiceNumber 
   AND H.YearMonthCode = D.YearMonthCode 
Where H.YearMonthCode = ymcode 
  AND D.ItemNumber = itm 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(H.LastChangeDate,'%m/%d/%YYYY') 
      Between Sdate AND Edate;
```

I call the procedure like this:

```
Call GetItemTotal('6458-20115','1311', '2013-11-15', '2013-11-30', @total)
```

Actually those would all be variables but I hard coded values for testing.

Both tables have PRIMARY indexes and index_YMC on the yearmonthcode columns.

Explain shows the following

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key       key_len ref   rows    extra

1  SIMPLE      H     ref  Index_YMC     Index_YMC 5       const 100408  Using where

1  SIMPLE      D     ALL  Index_YMC     null      null    null  2032249 Using where;
                                                                        Using join buffer
```

I am very new to database programming and if anyone can give me some ideas on how to make this query faster I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a reason to run each item separately? At the moment, you could expect similar performance from a query for all 600+ items (ie. 30 to 45 seconds) as your query for the same date range, for a single item.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could query all 600 items in the same query. The program actually creates a spread sheet with a total of 15 columns. The sum(OrderedQty) is only one of those columns. I will see if I can come up with a way to do what you suggest. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that the source for this routine is a list of the top 600 items in ascending order for the past 12 months.

Comment: Descending order not ascending

Comment: How is that list of the top 600 items over the past 12 months compiled - is there a separate query to rank the items (run immediately prior to calling the procedure), or do you have some kind of lookup table (or other precalculated method) to determine which should be included?

Comment: Also, how do you get 15 different columns out of the four (item, dates and total) apparently included in the procedure? Are you pivoting by date range across the sheet, and if so don't you need to call the procedure something like 12 times (once for each date range) per item?

Comment: OK Mark I will try to keep this explanation as simple as I can. There are basically two databases involved. The first database has among other things two tables Header and Detail for the current month. A second database has two almost identical Header and Detail tables. During the night of the last day of each month the data in the current month tables are copied to the history database tables and the YearMonthCode column is added to each record. When the program is run the user enters a start date and then the end date is calculated as the date 12 months ago.

Comment: Assuming the start date is in the current month the item numbers, sales volume and sales dollars are inserted into a temp table. Then the same data for the remaining months are inserted into the same temp table. Depending on whether the user selected to rank based on units or dollars I create another temp table where I insert the records grouped by either sum(dollarvalue) OR sum(unitssold). This is the table I use to start building the report. I now loop through the recordset from record 0 to 599 and either lookup (in other databases and tablestables) the information relative to that item.

Comment: It is this other information that causes the spreadsheet report to have a total of 15 columns. Columns like previous ranking, item description, vendor number, buyer code, Highest month sales, lowest months sales etc. The only column that is taking any time at all is the last seven days sales and that is the one that has me stumped!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already summing values for the entire year (in your population of the temp table), then I suggest adding another column to your temp table population query, derived something like:

```
sum(case when STR_TO_DATE(LastChangeDate,'%m/%d/%YYYY') Between Sdate AND Edate
         then OrderedQty
    end) as DateRangeTotal
```

This should remove the need for the `GetItemTotal` stored procedure altogether.

(You could probably make the rest of your processing more efficient by using set-based operations instead of looping through 600 items, but that's outside the scope of the question.)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion Mark however the lastchangedate is a field in the Header Table and when I sum values into the temp table I only sum the ordered Quantity and Dollar values for each item. Those fields are in the Detail table. I'm not sure how a join on those two tables during the summing of the full year would affect the speed but I'll give it a try.